# React NavLink change sub element according to isActive

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following link:

```
<NavLink to={x.url} className={(x) = x.isActive ? 'active' : 'not-active' } >
    <img src={`icon-default.svg`} /> // change from default.svg to active.svg       
    Link Text
</NavLink>
```

I have my icons inside the HTML and not the CSS, I want to call a different img according to isActive, is it possible to do it on a sub element (the `img` tag)?

`react-router-dom": "^6.0.2"`

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `children` prop of the `NavLink` also takes a function that is passed an `isActive` prop. The function must return a `ReactNode` (*i.e. JSX*).

[NavLink v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink)

> ```
> declare function NavLink(
>   props: NavLinkProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     LinkProps,
>     "className" | "style" | "children"
>   > {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?:
>     | React.ReactNode
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => string);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

Use a render function on the `children` prop to render the link content and conditionally set the image source attribute.

```
<NavLink
  to={x.url}
  className={({ isActive }) = isActive ? 'active' : 'not-active'}
  children={({ isActive }) => {
    const file = isActive ? "active" : "default";
    return (
      <>
        <img src={`icon-${file}.svg`} />
        {x.text}
      </>
    );
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thank, have a look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-v6-sample-byxy8d the img is not rendered...

Comment: @SexyMF I didn't have SVGs handy to test with, but cat pictures are usually a great stand-in. The above `isActive` logic appears to function as I'd expect here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-navlink-change-sub-element-according-to-isactive-8jeol). Your stackblitz doesn't appear to have the SVG images available/accessible in the `/public/assets/top-links/` directory.